# extjs dropdown menu creation with link inside

Tags: button, extjs, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I'm trying to do a dropdown menu with for each button in it, a link to a page.
I made the following code but I'm not able to create some link inside, i get an error each time :

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
layout: 'hbox',
width: 500,
height: 40,
margin: '10 0 0 10',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
floating: false,
items: [{
    text: 'Home'
},
{
    text: 'Inventory',
    menuAlign: 'tr-br',
    menu:{
        items:[
            {
                text: 'Show',
            },
            {
                text: 'Search'
            },
            {
                text: 'Service Catalog'
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    text: 'Request',
    menuAlign: 'tr-br',
    menu:{
        items:[
            {
                text: 'New Request'
            },
            {
                text: 'My requests'
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    text: 'Management',
    menuAlign: 'tr-br',
    menu:{
        items:[
            {
                text: 'Sites'
            },
            {
                text: 'Users'
            },
            {
                text: 'Stocks'
            },
            {
                text: 'Export'
            }
        ]
    }
},
]
});
```

Does anyone know how to create link in a button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution find :

I just added a handler in my code :

```
            {
                text: 'Search',
                handler : menuH
            },
```

and the handler :

```
var menuH = function() {
window.location = "/myapplication";
}
```